# Have similar functionality to a Folder in Start Menu on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am migrating from Windows XP to Windows 7.  On my Windows XP computers I keep a folder in \All Users\Start Menu.  This folder contained common shortcuts.  To access a shortcut in this folder I am able to press Ctrl-Esc and the first letter of the folder and I have access to all shortcuts.  It is VERY quick.  And at this point I subconsciously do this action to get access to my programs.

How can I create a folder with shortcuts in it which is easily accessible in Windows 7?  I can't seem to get a folder on the "Start Menu" which accepts keyboard accelerators.

Answer (score 1):

Try pinning the folder to the start menu and then, after you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>, press the <kbd>↑</kbd> and then the first letter of the folder name.  Not exactly the same, but close.

Comment: Yes - I am learning it is not possible to get rid of the "Search Box" (which is the reason you need to press the up arrow).

Comment: Actually, you can remove the search box using the process described here: http://www.dkszone.net/remove-search-box-windows-7-start-menu